# Matcher only finding the first instance in a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regulax expression to find a certain pattern inside a string, but I'm having some difficulties getting it to work properly. My code looks like this:

```
    public String regexTest(String test) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("A");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    while (m.find()) {
    return m.group();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Where the string test contains "A B C D A B A", but it just returns "A", while I want it to return "A", "A" and "A". 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you think **return** does?

Comment: while (m.find()){ sys.out(m.group());}

Comment: Why do you need to return *"A", "A" and "A"*? You can count and return the number of occurrences of `A` in `test` string, or return a List with all occurrences(which is what you've asked for, but it seems pretty strange to me).

Comment: @aga We can assume that "A" is just a test case.

Answer (score 1):

The matcher is like a cursor. You need to call `Matcher#find()` in order to go to the next result.

```
m.find()
m.group() // -> first result
m.find()
m.group() // -> second result
```

Comment: This does not address the problem.

Comment: IMHO op thought that `Matcher#group()' would return all the result. Instead I showed him how the `Matcher` is working, so he can fix the issue.

Comment: Calling `find()` in the `while` loop would have exactly the effect you describe.  Trouble is, he's calling `return` too, which exits the loop on the first hit.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning (aka exiting your method) after first match, so that is your problem i guess...

```
return m.group();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to return multiple values, you can't have just String as method return type. I suggest using `List<String>`. And then in the function, you must not return in the while loop, but add the string found to your result (which should start out as the empty list).